# How can I can I get from Zaventem train station to the airport?

Tags: airport-transfer, brussels

I recently went to Brussels airport and ended up in Zaventem for practical reasons. Since I had some time I ended up walking which is quite doable (if you like it).

I was wondering if there are Buses to the airport. I googled around and best solution found was in rome2rio bus nr272.

I any case I don't know how frequent this is, if there are other alternatives and the price.

**How can I can I get from Zaventem train station to the airport?**

Comment: Two great answers, please mark one "Accepted" if you are satisfied. Many thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Accurate as 15 Feb 2017**

By train or bus. Brussels Airport has their own underground train & bus station.

You can look for public transport possibilities [on the website of the national traincompany (NMBS in flemish, SNCB in french)](http://www.belgianrail.be/jp/sncb-nmbs-routeplanner/query.exe/en) or on the website of the [Flemish busses(De Lijn)](https://www.delijn.be/nl/routeplanner/resultaten.html?from=Station%20Zaventem%20%5BB%5D&startXCoordinaat=157117&startYCoordinaat=175045&to=Brussels%20Airport%2C%20Zaventem&finishXCoordinaat=158094&finishYCoordinaat=176021&datum=16-02-2017&departureChoice=1&tijd=14%3A24&option-bus=on&option-tram=on&option-metro=on&option-trein=on&option-belbus=off). Both sites should give the same results (both give trains and busses)

I can't give you a link to results because that search query expires.

### Train

Fill in the route planner as in the example below. (Luchthaven means airport)
[image: Search query example]

On weekdays there seems to be 1 train/hour, which takes 4 minutes. This would cost you **€7.50** one way. (prices do change almost every year though)
[image: Train result]

### Bus

You can also take the bus from Zaventem station to the airport. This will take between 15 - 20 minutes, depending on which bus. (This is also a week day result)
You can use the website from the busses company 
[image: Busses result]
**Prices may change and were from 16/02/2017**
Busses are a bit cheaper. There are serveral tickets you can buy. Thinking you will only take the bus once:

- 1 way ticket: **€3**  easiest, can buy on the bus(cash), from a machine or in the bus station. (sometimes you can buy it from the train station people too)
- SMS ticket: **€2 + €0.15** (for the sms itself), cheaper than 1 way ticket. Valid for 1 hour from the moment you send your SMS. (depends on what you put in the message). Only works with [these mobile operators](https://www.delijn.be/en/vervoerbewijzen/ritkaarten-dagpassen/overzicht-gsm-operatoren-sms-ticket.html)

Both are only valid for 60 minutes.

Comment: Does the price to the airport include the airport fee?

Comment: @nsn: Yes, the Diabolo surcharge is included in the 7,50 EUR.

Comment: +1, what a great answer. Since prices and schedules are a volatile market I suggest you headline your answer with a "accurate as 15 Feb 2017" or something similar. Best at the top in bold face, but it's your call...

Comment: Good idea, I'll edit my answer to make that clear!

Answer (score 6):

The best solution depends on where exactly in Zaventem you are. You can find this info on [the website of De Lijn](https://www.delijn.be/). There's a facility to find a bus based on departure and arrival points (routeplanner, airport is Luchthaven in Dutch) and a line schedule (dienstregeling).

Line 272 is indeed a possibility

https://www.delijn.be/en/lijnen/lijn/3/272/1/272_Zaventem_-_Brussel

Every half hour line 359 goes to the airport, with 6 stops on the territory of Zaventem.

https://www.delijn.be/en/lijnen/lijn/3/359/2/359_Roodebeek_-_Zaventem

There's also line 282 (Mechelen-Zaventem) also runs every half hour during the day

https://www.delijn.be/en/lijnen/lijn/3/282/1/282_Mechelen_-_Zaventem

The english translation isn't ideal, but it should be easy to figure out the info you need.

Cost: there is [a fixed price for a ticket valid for a single trip](https://www.delijn.be/en/vervoerbewijzen/ritkaarten-dagpassen/biljet-enkele-rit.html), it will cost you 3 Euros.